# How can I extend KIE/jbpm with custom types of assets?

Tags: module, drools, extend, jbpm, kie

KIE Workbench comes with a set of asset types, e.g. Guided Rule, Form, Business Process, etc. I would like to extend KIE/JBPM with a new type of asset that is specific to my business. This asset would require to be included in the packaging, be able to expose an additional endpoint and extend the KIE Workbench user interface.

I haven't been successful in finding this option in the documentation as of yet. In the mean time I started analysing the sources, but given the size of the project, reverse engineering this will take quite some time.

This question is about KIE 7.x

Comment: You just want to include your business specific assets into project or you want to modify them from workbench as well ?

Comment: You can expose additional end points(KIE-Extensions) and include business assets in the kjar. But modifying the WorkBench UI would be a significant effort.

Comment: Initially I'd start with adding business specific assets to the kjar and exposing those assets using a kie-server-extension. I can't find much documentation on how to write kie-server-extensions though. 

Once that's done, I'd like to extend the workbench so that I can author those assets from within the workbench. Why is this a lot of effort?